# Hosting webgl game on dropbox and use it with facebook secure canvas

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, canvas, dropbox, unity-webgl

I have a webgl game and I want to put it in facebook secure canvas. Since dropbox is https secure, I want to upload the game there and paste the link to the facebook secure canvas settings, but I got this error:

```
must point to a directory (i.e., end with a '/' or a dynamic page (i.e., have a '?' somewhere).
```

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that facebook does not like static HTML pages. Try changing the Secure Canvas URL to include ?secure (or any other word/variables as long as it starts with a question mark). Meaning:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public/whatever/index2.html?secure
```

Hope it helps!